# Why stopPropagation() helps when registered on $(document)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, stoppropagation

So the problem is that one of my click events was firing twice for no good reason. Here is the function

```
function submitVoteFormOnClick() {
    $(document).off('click', '.vote-form');
    $(document).on('click', '.vote-form', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var $arrow = $(e.target);
        $arrow.siblings('.vote-value').val($arrow.data('value'));
        console.log('my click');
        console.log(e.timeStamp);
        console.log($arrow);
        $arrow.closest('form').submit();
    });
}
```

So I added the stopPropagation after too much time out of despair, and it worked, and I don't understand why!! Where does it propagate if it is registered on the document? Anyone can explain?

**EDIT**

Here is also the necessary mark-up

```
<div id='page-wrapper'>
  <div class='bottom-index-part'>
    <div class='index'>
      <div class='event-body'>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class='event-times'>
              <div id='EventTime-17'>
                <span class='vote-form'>
                    <form method="post" data-remote="true" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/votes/30" data-toggle="tooltip" id="edit_vote_30" title="" class="form-inline vote-form" data-original-title="1">
                    <input type="hidden" id="vote_value" name="vote[value]" value="1" class="vote-value">
                    <input type="hidden" id="vote_votable_type" name="vote[votable_type]" value="EventTime">
                    <input type="hidden" id="vote_votable_id" name="vote[votable_id]" value="17">
                    <i data-value="1" class="fa fa-caret-up clickable submit-up-vote active"></i>
                    <i data-value="-1" class="fa fa-caret-down clickable submit-down-vote "></i>
                    </form>
                  </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you have an additional event listener somewhere.

Comment: Could be nested `.vote-form` elements, so that the click event bubbling would trigger both of them.

Comment: @Oriol don't have other listener. If you actually looked, you'd see I checked it with logging. It registered only once, but fired twice.
No nested form-elements

Comment: @Slaaavo Then maybe you have repeated `.vote-form` elements as Daniel said. But there is some duplicity somewhere, event listeners aren't normally called twice. We can't know what's happening because you didn't provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @Oriol I have added the necessary mark-up. I tried to do a jsfiddle but for whatever reason it didn't do anything